# Flutter ios-framework build failed issue

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, flutter-build, flutter-module

I have an old app which writen with flutter 1.22.6 (i know its really old) and i have to embed my app to another native app with FlutterView (i know it doesn't make sense to embed an entire app to another but customers are always right :)). Therefore i converted my flutter project to flutter module project and now im trying to take a framework build for ios. When i run the command `fvm flutter build ios-framework` it starts the process perfectly until Building plugins... when it reach to Building plugins, it gives error:

`Unable to build plugin frameworks: 2023-08-18 10:56:39.784 xcodebuild[4194:69386] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)
** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
SwiftVerifyEmittedModuleInterface normal arm64 Verifying\ emitted\ module\ interface\ keyboard_utils.private.swiftinterface /Users/path/path/path/build/ios/framework/Debug/iphoneos/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/keyboard_utils.build/Objects-normal/arm64/keyboard_utils.private.swiftinterface (in target 'keyboard_utils' from project 'Pods')
SwiftVerifyEmittedModuleInterface normal arm64 Verifying\ emitted\ module\ interface\ keyboard_utils.swiftinterface /Users/path/path/path/build/ios/framework/Debug/iphoneos/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/keyboard_utils.build/Objects-normal/arm64/keyboard_utils.swiftinterface (in target 'keyboard_utils' from project 'Pods')
(2 failures)`

I really couldn't find any working solution for my case, so if anyone can help me is gonna save my day :)

thanks a lot in advance